# Android Service class... keeping track of multiple instances of a service

Tags: android

I am about to begin messing around with Services and I was wondering if there is a way to keep track of what services are running. Is there a PID I can have returned and store in some container along with my data pertaining to that service so that at a later time I can bring up an activity and it present to me a list of the services I have running? Basically looking to write a Service that can be spawned multiple ways with different settings.

Answer (score 3):

> keeping track of multiple instances of a service

There are never "multiple instances of a service". There will be exactly 0 or 1 instances of a service.

Comment: what if I had something like an Auction Watcher where I was watching 7 different items with 7 different prices going off at 7 different times whos prices I needed to monitor

Comment: @Andrew: That is one service that is watching "7 different items with 7 different prices", preferably an `IntentService` driven by `AlarmManager`.